# Is this “career ladder” HR tool commonly used?

Tags: human-resources, performance, payscale

My first job was with a large multinational that had a very comprehensive HR department. When I joined the company, HR gave new employees a lot of useful information, including a “career ladder” table.

Now that I’m a small business owner, I would like to develop a similar “career ladder” table for my team. I remember it being very useful, but otherwise my memory is hazy, and so I thought I’d try to search for some examples and inspiration. So far, no luck.

If I recall, this table had “levels” down the left hand side, e.g., junior, associate, senior, etc. Across the top of the table were column heading describing various areas of competence, e.g., communications, new business development, etc. In each cell of the table was a short narrative describing the expected responsibilities/ performance for each level and area of competency. The table was useful in establishing expectations,  during performance reviews, and also discussing pay scales.

So my questions area:

1. Is this a commonly used HR tool, or is it something that this particularly company developed internally?
2. If it is a common tool, does it have a name? What should I search for in Google to find examples?

After much fruitless searching, Stackexchange is my last hope. Hopefully this question is appropriate for this forum and someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What would be the advantage of it? I've seen it in use and it only lead to unnecessary gaming of the KPI system with precious little in the way of actual value to either the management or the employees. In some career paths, it can even create a blocker for advancement that would not exist in other (hint: more lucrative for the employee...) companies.

Comment: Thanks @JuhaUntinen, you may be right. I guess that’s why I wanted to study some examples. Also, presumably much depends on the dynamics of the team in which it is applied. It sounds like you’ve come across this before. Can you point me towards any examples or useful search terms? Thanks!

Comment: It was a completely in-house framework, so I doubt there are examples available publicly. I'm fairly sure such a system would always be cpmpany-specific. There *may* be some guidelines in ITIL, but not in depth: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL

Answer (score 1):

This would be something the company developed internally, because each company would have different criteria for advancement.

I haven't seen a template.

For your own company a bit of thought would enable you to create your own, just decide what would be needed for each level. You know your company best. It's unlikely to be a perfect fit with any one elses.

Comment: Thanks Kilisi, yes I agree with you the details of the tool would need to be company specific. My question was more aimed towards is the generic tool in common usage, or specific to this company. Really just wondering what terms to put into Google to view some examples

Comment: It's fairly common to list certifications that would be required to advance to certain position, but not a full on tool like you outlined. That's a huge amount of work which doesn't make business sense to produce unless it's a very big company with a lot of HR sitting on their hands.